# Get Multiple Dynamically added Material Autocomplete input to call same method on valueChange

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, angular-material

Thanks for reading.

I have a page where a user can input and select an address from an autocomplete.
The source of the autocomplete is from an external API, which is called using the valueChanges event.

The resultant behaviour is that of a predictive address lookup based on user input.
This works currently for this singular purpose.

```html
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Search Multi" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchMoviesCtrl" type="text">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of filteredMovies" [value]="suggestion.text">
            <span><b>{{suggestion.text}}</b></span>
          </mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

    <br>

  <ng-container *ngIf="errorMsg; else elseTemplate">
    {{errorMsg}}
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <h5>Selected Value: {{searchMoviesCtrl.value}}</h5>
  </ng-template>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { debounceTime, tap, switchMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchMoviesCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredMovies: any;
  isLoading = false;
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchMoviesCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        tap(() => {
          this.errorMsg = "";
          this.filteredMovies = [];
          this.isLoading = true;
        }),
        switchMap(value => this.http.get("http://searchaddressapiurl?text=" + this.searchMoviesCtrl.value)
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
              this.isLoading = false
            }),
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Search text :' + this.searchMoviesCtrl.value);
        console.log(data);

        if (data['suggestions'] == undefined) {
          this.errorMsg = data['Error'];
          this.filteredMovies = [];
          console.log('coming here ERROR');
        } else {
          this.errorMsg = "";
          this.filteredMovies = data['suggestions'];
          console.log('coming here');
        }


        console.log(this.filteredMovies);
      });
  }

displayFn(suggestion : string) : string {
    console.log('Display - ' + suggestion);
    return suggestion ? suggestion : '';
  }
}
```

However, I want to allow the user to add additional autocomplete inputs, which will use/call the same API on value change.

How best can I go about this?

I have been able to get the adding of multiple inputs going by doing the below.
I'm just not sure how to go about hooking up these inputs to a valueChange function which calls the search API passing through the entered text...ideally one function that caters for all inputs

```html
<form [formGroup]="autocompleteForm" novalidate >
        <div formArrayName="sites">
            <div *ngFor="let unit of autocompleteForm.controls.sites.controls; let i=index" class="form-group">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div style="width: 100%;">

                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput placeholder="Search Multi" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="site" type="text" (input)="searchSite(this, i)">
                        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                        <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of filteredAddresses" [value]="suggestion.text">
                            <span><b>{{suggestion.text}}</b></span>
                            </mat-option>
                        </ng-container>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <button (click)="addSite()">Add Site</button>
        </div>

    <ng-container *ngIf="errorMsg; else elseTemplate">
        {{errorMsg}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #elseTemplate>
        <h5>Selected Value: {{site.value}}</h5>
    </ng-template>

</form>
```

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.autocompleteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      sites: this.formBuilder.array([
         // load first row at start
         this.getSite()
      ])
    });

  displayFn(suggestion : string) : string {
    console.log('Display - ' + suggestion);
    return suggestion ? suggestion : '';
  }

  public searchSite(obj, index)
  {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(index + ' - ' + obj);
  }

  private getSite() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      site: ['', [Validators.required]
    });
  }

  addSite() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.autocompleteForm.controls['sites'];
    control.push(this.getSite());
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I've udpdated the searchSite method that gets called on input changes...
It allows for the inputs to call the searchSite method.

It does the job of getting back the necessary resultset but it makes many unnecessary API calls seemingly, I figure this because of the (input) onchange call and the .valueChanges event hookup.

Still a work in progress at this point but just putting up some of the progress.
Ideas still welcome.

```
public searchSite(obj : MultiAutoCompleteComponent, index)
  {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(index + ' - ' + obj);
    console.log(obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.value[index].site);
    console.log('Input value : ' + obj.autocompleteForm.controls);

    var searchText = obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.value[index].site;

    if(searchText.length < 2 || searchText == '' || searchText == null || searchText == undefined || searchText === -1)
    {
      console.log('Minimum not provided');
      return;
    }

    obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        tap(() => {
          this.errorMsg = "";
          this.filteredAddresses = [];
          this.isLoading = true;
        }),
        switchMap(value => this.http.get("http://searchaddressapi?text=" + searchText)
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
              this.isLoading = false
            }),
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Search text :' + this.site.value);
        console.log(data);

        if (data['suggestions'] == undefined) {
          this.errorMsg = data['Error'];
          this.filteredAddresses = [];
          console.log('Search site coming here ERROR');
        } else {
          this.errorMsg = "";
          this.filteredAddresses = data['suggestions'];
          console.log('Search site coming here');
        }


        console.log(this.filteredAddresses);
      });

  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

So I have made some changes, this results in the autocomplete working as expected for my use case. (Adding dynamic Multi autocompletes which call the same API)

Just one thing I would still like to address...the calls to the API on each char input.

I tried to address this by using debounceTime but this didn't seem to have an effect, it delayed the calls but they were still made (all of them per char) instead of ignoring those calls sent during the debounceTime. At least that is what I thought would/should happen?

Is my understanding of the deboundTime behaviour incorrect?

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

searchTextChanged = new Subject<string>();

public searchSite(obj : MultiAutoCompleteComponent, index)
  {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(index + ' - ' + obj);
    console.log(obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.value[index].site);
    console.log('Input value : ' + obj.autocompleteForm.controls);

    var searchText = obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.value[index].site;

    const items = this.autocompleteForm.get('sites') as FormArray;
    console.log('No of sites added: ' + items.length);


    if(searchText.length < 5 || searchText == '' || searchText == null || searchText == undefined || searchText === -1)
    {
      console.log('Minimum not provided, no serarch conducted');
      return;
    }
    else
    { 
        this.searchTextChanged.next(searchText);

        this.searchTextChanged
          .pipe(
            debounceTime(1000),
            tap(() => {
              this.errorMsg = "";
              this.filteredAddresses = [];
              this.isLoading = true;
            }),
            switchMap(value => this.http.get("http://searchaddressapi?text=" + searchText)
              .pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                  this.isLoading = false
                }),
              )
            )
          )
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Search text :' + searchText);
            console.log(data);

            if (data['suggestions'] == undefined) {
              this.errorMsg = data['Error'];
              this.filteredAddresses = [];
              console.log('Search site coming here ERROR');
            } else {
              this.errorMsg = "";
              this.filteredAddresses = data['suggestions'];
              console.log('Search site coming here');
            }


            console.log(this.filteredAddresses);
          });
    }

  }
```

What am I doing wrong re. the debounceTime delay implementation?

**UPDATE 3 - SOLVED**

I got this to work as needed!

Dynamically add additional autocompletes which make use of the same API for data result set.

The debounceTime reduces the number of API calls when a user is inputting searchText.

I'm sure you can clean this up and as suggested by one commenter put the API call in a service but here it is anyway.

```
//multi-auto-complete.component.css
.example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .example-full-width {
    width: 100%;
  }

//multi-auto-complete.component.html
<div>

<form [formGroup]="autocompleteForm" novalidate >
            <div formArrayName="sites">
                <div *ngFor="let unit of autocompleteForm.controls.sites.controls; let i=index" class="form-group">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div style="width: 100%;">

                        <mat-form-field>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Search Multi" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="site" type="text" (input)="searchSite(this, i)">
                            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                            <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of filteredAddresses" [value]="suggestion.text">
                                <span><b>{{suggestion.text}}</b></span>
                                </mat-option>
                            </ng-container>
                            </mat-autocomplete>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <button (click)="addSite()">Add Site</button>
            </div>

        <ng-container *ngIf="errorMsg; else elseTemplate">
            {{errorMsg}}
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #elseTemplate>
            <h5>Selected Value: {{site.value}}</h5>
        </ng-template>

    </form>

</div>
```

```
//multi-auto-complete.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, ɵConsole } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { debounceTime, tap, switchMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';


export interface Suggestion {
  text: string;
  magicKey: string;
  isCollection: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-multi-auto-complete',
  templateUrl: './multi-auto-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multi-auto-complete.component.css']
})
export class MultiAutoCompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  site = new FormControl();
  filteredAddresses: any;
  isLoading = false;
  errorMsg: string;

  autocompleteForm: FormGroup;

  results$: Observable<any>;
  searchTextChanged = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) 
  { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.autocompleteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      sites: this.formBuilder.array([
         // load first row at start
         this.getSite()
      ])
    });

    this.results$ = this.searchTextChanged.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(searchText => this.http.get("http://searchaddressapi?text=" + searchText)))

      console.log(this.results$.subscribe(data => { 
        this.filteredAddresses = data['suggestions'];
        console.log(data)
      }));

  }

  displayFn(suggestion : string) : string {
    console.log('Displaying selection - ' + suggestion);
    this.filteredAddresses = [];
    return suggestion ? suggestion : '';
  }

  public searchSite(obj : MultiAutoCompleteComponent, index)
  {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(index + ' - ' + obj);
    console.log(obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.value[index].site);
    console.log('Input value : ' + obj.autocompleteForm.controls);

    var searchText = obj.autocompleteForm.controls.sites.value[index].site;

    //const items = this.autocompleteForm.get('sites') as FormArray;
    //console.log('No of sites added: ' + items.length);


    if(searchText.length < 5 || searchText == '' || searchText == null || searchText == undefined || searchText === -1)
    {
      console.log('Minimum characters not provided, no search conducted');
      return;
    }
    else
    { 
        this.searchTextChanged.next(searchText);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Create form site
   */
  private getSite() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      site: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  /**
   * Add new site row into form
   */
  addSite() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.autocompleteForm.controls['sites'];
    control.push(this.getSite());

    this.filteredAddresses = [];
  }

}
```

Comment: You should take out the API call from component and put it in a service (see the link attached). Then create a function in your component, which will call this service and handle the response data from the service. You can then hook this function directly to your HTML elements using a onValueChange event attribute.


https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: @pkimtani, hi thanks for your response, yes thanks, that will be most ideal re. moving the API call into a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work as needed!

Dynamically add additional autocompletes which make use of the same API for data result set.

The debounceTime reduces the number of API calls when a user is inputting searchText.

I'm sure you can clean this up and as suggested by one commenter put the API call in a service but here it is anyway.

Please see **UPDATE 3** in my Question Post for the code!